# PyCharm Community 3.1.1 and Numpy, "'matrix' is not callable", but the code works

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = np.matrix([[1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1]])
    print(m)
```

The code runs as expected, but PyCharm seems to think that 'matrix' is not callable. See screenshot.

[image]

Since the code runs, clearly 'matrix' is callable. So what's PyCharm complaining about? Am I in the wrong here or is PyCharm? How do I suppress this error?

Comment: You've described the situation. What's the question?

Comment: Hehe oops! Forgot about the question! I'll edit.

Comment: PyCharm is in the wrong. You should [report](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY) it as a bug to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround, at least until the bug is fixed, is to use `np.mat(...)` instead of `np.matrix(...)`.

However, note that `np.mat` will avoid making copies if the input is already a matrix and so you can't use it to do things like make defensive copies.