# Python: Is PyCharm broken? Or i am broken maybe? Or both?

Tags: python, pycharm

PyCharm community edition 3.4.1 running for Python 2.7.8.
Simple code:

```
def test(x):
    print x

d={'test': test}
d['test'](5)
```

Gives

```
d['test'](5)
```

'Null is not callable'

In the shell this code executes error-free.

Comment: please fix your indentation

Comment: Is that the actual traceback message?

Comment: Sorry for the indent.

Comment: executes fine in pycharm ... copy/paste exactly the code from this question and it should run...

Comment: Try adding `print test, id(test), type(test), d['test']` before the line `d['test'](5)`. See if they actually are null?

Comment: @gargiulo2000 Do you mean your error appears in this form? [PyCharm Community 3.1.1 and Numpy, “'matrix' is not callable”, but the code works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635315/pycharm-community-3-1-1-and-numpy-matrix-is-not-callable-but-the-code-work)

Comment: The statement says: This inspection highlights attempts to call objects which are not callable, like, for example, tuples. BUT the code actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in inspection seems to be oversensitive (or buggy if you will).

If you try `(d['test'])(5)` then it won't complaint.

Comment: i'm new to python and programming. 8h to figure out what was wrong. It was cute actually.

Comment: it isn't an issue with python - more than pyCharm (which is one tool you can use if you want) which has an issue.

Comment: PyShame is the new name